# Limit points of a sequence $z_n=1+i^n\frac{n}{n+1}$ of complex numbers.

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to find all the limit points of the following sequence:
$$z_n=1+i^n\frac{n}{n+1}$$
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Look at the sub-sequences

$$b_{n}\equiv a_{4n+k},\:\:k\in\{0,1,2,3\}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\dfrac{n}{1+n}\to1$ as $n\to\infty$, then $z_n\to2,0,1+i,1-i$.

Answer (score 1):

Those are $1+\{-1,1,i,-i\}=\color{red}{\{0,2,1+i,1-i\}}$ Given that $\dfrac{n}{1+n}\to1$ and $i^n\in \{-1,1,i,-i\}.$